# Android ProGuard keepattributes how to filter some specified attributes?

Tags: android, proguard

I want to package AAB not include debugging and stack traces informations.

In our project‘s third party SDKs there include this rule:
“-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable”

and how can i write in the main project ProGuard file to invalidate this rule.